# bash rotation script

Tags: linux, find, backup, rm

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
backup-2018-01-12
backup-2018-01-13
backup-2018-01-14
backup-2018-01-15
backup-2018-01-16
backup-2018-01-17
backup-2018-01-18
backup-2018-01-19
backup-2018-01-20
backup-2018-01-21
backup-2018-01-22
backup-2018-01-23
backup-2018-01-24
backup-2018-01-25
backup-2018-01-26
backup-2018-01-27
backup-2018-01-28
backup-2018-01-29
backup-2018-01-30
backup-2018-01-31
backup-2018-02-01
backup-2018-02-02
backup-2018-02-03
backup-2018-02-04
backup-2018-02-05
backup-2018-02-06
backup-2018-02-07
backup-2018-02-08
backup-2018-02-09
backup-2018-02-10
backup-2018-02-11
backup-2018-02-12
backup-2018-02-13
backup-2018-02-14
backup-2018-02-15
```

How can I use a script to save the latest 7 days and the the last backup of each week for 4 weeks long

E.g

So I keep

```
backup-2018-01-25  <-- this is 3 waeks from now and so on. 
backup-2018-02-02  <-- this is 2 weeks earlier from now
backup-2018-02-09
backup-2018-02-10
backup-2018-02-11
backup-2018-02-12
backup-2018-02-13
backup-2018-02-14
backup-2018-02-15
```

So I tried

`find -type d -name 'backup-*' -mtime +7 -exec rm -v {} \;`

and this does keep the latest 7 but removes everything older than 7 days.

Comment: Some use dedicated backup software for these types of tasks (i.e. backing up data and keeping backups of certain ages), like `borgbackup` or `borgmatic` (which uses `borgbackup`).

Comment: I see not obvious tools for the jobs, facing similar problem i wrote a c program.

Comment: This is the first hit on Google for this type of backup retention which is my primary requirement. However, I'm looking for something with a GUI, unless I'm forced to use a script so I created a post in SE-software-reqs here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/84066/linux-ubuntu-backup-with-incremental-and-smart-retention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a straightforward solution. The easiest way I found to solve it was to use a "keep" list rather than a "remove" list. Then I could add the last N backups to the list, and the newest of each week's range for M weeks. (In my own code, written some time ago, I extended to months, quarters, and years.) Obviously there will be some overlap but because it's a "keep" list that doesn't matter. Then you delete everything that isn't in the list - having first checked the list isn't empty.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
dirs=(
    backup-2018-01-12
    backup-2018-01-13
    backup-2018-01-14
    backup-2018-01-15
    backup-2018-01-16
    backup-2018-01-17
    backup-2018-01-18
    backup-2018-01-19
    backup-2018-01-20
    backup-2018-01-21
    backup-2018-01-22
    backup-2018-01-23
    backup-2018-01-24
    backup-2018-01-25
    backup-2018-01-26
    backup-2018-01-27
    backup-2018-01-28
    backup-2018-01-29
    backup-2018-01-30
    backup-2018-01-31
    backup-2018-02-01
    backup-2018-02-02
    backup-2018-02-03
    backup-2018-02-04
    backup-2018-02-05
    backup-2018-02-06
    backup-2018-02-07
    backup-2018-02-08
    backup-2018-02-09
    backup-2018-02-10
    backup-2018-02-11
    backup-2018-02-12
    backup-2018-02-13
    backup-2018-02-14
    backup-2018-02-15
)
declare -A list
declare -A keep


####################################################################################
# Go
#
prefix="backup-"
today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)


# Populate list from set of directories
#
for item in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    list[$item]="$item"
done


# Build keep list from business criteria
#
for dayback in {0..6}
do
    dateback=$(date --date "$today - $dayback day" +%Y-%m-%d)
    keep[$prefix$dateback]=1
done

for weekback in {0..3}
do
    dateback1=$(date --date "$today - $weekback week" +%Y-%m-%d)
    dateback2=$(date --date "$today - $((weekback + 1)) week" +%Y-%m-%d)

    # Look for newest in range
    #
    newest=
    dateback="$dateback1"
    while [[ $dateback != $dateback2 ]]
    do
        [[ -n ${list[$prefix$dateback]} ]] && newest=$dateback && break
        dateback=$(date --date "$dateback - 1 day" +%Y-%m-%d)
    done

    [[ -n $newest ]] && keep[$prefix$newest]=1
done


# We now have a keep list, so delete anything not in that list
#
for item in "${list[@]}"
do
    [[ -n ${keep[$item]} ]] && echo "KEEP $item" || echo "DELETE $item"
done


# All done
#
exit 0
```

When you're happy, change or extend the echo statements towards the end to perform the actual deletion.

Comment: I have used a similar solution in the past, where I kept directories for daily, weekly, and monthly backups, and just moved files around, and kept various numbers of files in each directory.  I like the idea of a keep list, though.

Comment: @roaima awesome! It almost working. What if directory is `/some/path/backup-*`  how to dael with this?

Comment: I think I fixing the problem. Thanks Roaima

Comment: @roaima , How can i make this work when dir is like `dirs= ( /var/lib/somepath/data/*/*/*/backups/backup-*)`  where under `data` there are different directories each with `backups/backup-*`  .  This work when the script is located in the same location as `backups-*`  the above.

Comment: @holasz I'd discard the concept of a `$prefix` entirely, and instead just build a set of dates to keep. I'd then compare the date component of the backup directory paths to the set of dates I'd generated, deleting the directories for which there was no match. I suspect it's a harder problem to solve than the one you described in your question, though.

Comment: @roaima this means I don't know where to start. I don't think I can solve it. If for you it's a small effort I would immensly appreciate it.

Comment: @roaima sorry for the trouble. Been able to solve it! Thanks again for your script.

Answer (score 1):

Whats about this?

```
for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1); do 
    if ! (( $((($(date +%s) - $(date +%s -r $i )) / 86400)) % 7)); then 
        echo $i # Print out the folder. Can be replaced with your action
    fi
done
```

or as oneliner:

```
for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1); do if ! (( $((($(date +%s) - $(date +%s -r $i )) / 86400)) % 7)); then echo "$i $i_weekly" ;fi; done
```

This should just print all folders which should be 7,14,21,28.... days old. 
Instead of "echo" just make a mv or what ever...

Comment: @Marcc, doesn't seem to show nothing

Comment: may be you need to change the path of the find command. The "." means use the current working directory, so change in the parent dir of your backups first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example script to rotate backups but keep last 7 days, 12 monthes `backup-*-*-01` and 10 years `backup-*-01-01`

```bsh
all=$(ls backup-*)
days=$(ls backup-* | tail -n 7)
monthes=$(ls backup-*-01 | tail -n 12)
years=$(ls backup-*-01-01 | tail -n 10)
keep=" $days $monthes $years "

for item in $all
do
    if ! [[ "$keep" =~ "$item" ]]
    then
        echo "$item will be deleted"
        # rm $item
    fi
done
```

Comment: Don't use `ls` - it isn't needed or wanted. Try running this BUT replacing the 'rm $item' with 'echo $item'.

Comment: @JeremyBoden thank you for the comment, I have replaced unsafe `rm` with an `echo` example, also I'm not sure what did you mean by saying that `ls` isn't needed, can you please describe it a little bit more, I have tried something like `all=$(backup-*); echo $all` with no luck

Comment: You are probably OK with `ls` in this case since you know that all names won't have spaces etc in them. Also you (hopefully) will get filenames in date sequence (which would allow the `tail` commands to work properly). I always try to avoid using `ls` in scripts...